# Microsoft Power Automate Alternative for listening events in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, power-automate

Goal:
Listen to events in Azure DevOps and automate workflows in Azure DevOps, like closing the tasks etc,.

Efforts:
I am using MS Power Automate to listen to events in Azure DevOps but it seems to work too slow (1-2 mins since the trigger).

Suggestion Required:
Do we have any alternative to MS Power Automate that can reduce the time ?

Answer (score 2):

You may try to programmatically create a subscription using the [Subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/hooks/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) REST APIs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/create-subscription?view=azure-devops

Here's a sample to help you get started:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Microsoft.Samples.VisualStudioOnline
{
    public class ServiceHookEventController : Controller
    {

        // POST: /ServiceHookEvent/workitemcreated
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage WorkItemCreated(Content workItemEvent)
        {
            //Grabbing the title for the new workitem
            var value = RetrieveFieldValue("System.field", workItemEvent.Resource.Fields);

            //Acknowledge event receipt
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the value for a specified work item field.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">Key used to retrieve matching value</param>
        /// <param name="fields">List of fields for a work item</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public String RetrieveFieldValue(String key, IList<FieldInfo> fields)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                return String.Empty;

            var result = fields.Single(s => s.Field.RefName == key);

            if (result == null)
                return String.Empty;

            return result.Value;
        }

    }

    public class Content
    {
        public String SubscriptionId { get; set; }

        public int NotificationId { get; set; }

        public String EventType { get; set; }

        public WorkItemResource Resource { get; set; }

    }

    public class WorkItemResource
    {
        public String UpdatesUrl { get; set; }

        public IList<FieldInfo> Fields { get; set;}

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int Rev { get; set; }

        public String Url { get; set; }

        public String WebUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class FieldInfo
    {
        public FieldDetailedInfo Field { get; set; }

        public String Value { get; set; }

    }

    public class FieldDetailedInfo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public String Name { get; set; }

        public String RefName { get; set; }
    }
}
```